# Positioning child behind parent

Tags: z-index

I'm trying to position a child element behind it's parent:

```
<div><p>test</p></div>
```

My CSS is:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 2;
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The `z-index` of the `<p>` is lower than it's parent `z-index`, but it is displayed in front. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's possible in your situation, you need to prevent stacking context on the parent. To do so, remove the `z-index` from your `<div/>` and set the `<p/>`'s `z-index` to `-1`:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    /* z-index: 2; */
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `div` and the `p` in the example exist on different stacking contexts, and the `div`'s `z-index` tells it to appear two levels higher than its **siblings**, not its children.

However, an element's `z-index` that is below zero puts it behind its parent.

Giving the `p` a `z-index` of -1 puts the `p` behind the `div`, regardless of the `div`'s `z-index`.